# changing the type of Retrieved in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel as API and here is my question, when I want to retrieve table named Tags which has ['id','name','post_id'] ,I Serialize this as you can see below

```
$tags = Tag::all();
        $temp=[];
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $temp[] = $tag->name;
        }
        return response()->json($temp);
```

is there any best practice to do that because when I want to do the same for multiple tables it would be bothering ...

Comment: `Tag::all()->toArray();`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-toarray

Comment: I've just edited that. i just want name attribute be added to array

Comment: `Tag::get(['name']);`. get only name then.

Comment: they are still inside array, i want them to be in this style $tags=['first tag','second tag','...']

Comment: Using `pluck` you can get single column value as an array like this,
`$tags = Tag::pluck('name')->toArray();`

Comment: thanks,it works.but when I use pluck in relations I get this error : "Method addEagerConstraints does not exist."

Comment: do not use pluck in relation you can use it on array of collection check the manual.

Comment: like, if you have tags with somthing in it. you can use like,
$tags->somthing->pluck('name');

Comment: if it solved your issue then should i post my answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `pluck` to get array of single column values,
like,

```
$tags = Tag::pluck('name')->toArray();
```

If you want to use pluck on relation you can do like this,

```
$posts = Posts::with('tags')->all();
foreach($posts as $post){
 $post->tag_name = $post->tags->pluck('tag_name');
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($posts);
```

Now you get your tag name in posts array using key tag_name.

Comment: If it solved your issue then do not forget to mark as a right answer.
thank you.

Comment: Thnk you so much. :)

Comment: When I  use  $post->tags->pluck('tag_name'); and dd($posts) , pluck didn't work

Comment: you had stored that into any ??

Comment: you have to store it in post like, let me edit my answer

Comment: can I store instead of tags?

Comment: yup you can store every iteration just like this.

Comment: but sure before do. check dd(); and go further.